# HelloWorld tutorial doesn't work for android 2.3.3, attrs.xml missing

Tags: android, windows-7

I am new to Android programming and decided to start with the tutorial on my 64-bit windows 7 box.

Following the tutorial, I created a new project targeting android 2.3.3, the most popular one. However, Eclipse reported errors as:

```
[2011-08-04 21:50:06 - Android Framework Parser] Menu declare-styleable MenuGroup not found in file C:\Android\android-sdk\platforms\android-10\data\res\values\attrs.xml
[2011-08-04 21:50:06 - Android Framework Parser] Searchable declare-styleable Searchable not found in file C:\Android\android-sdk\platforms\android-10\data\res\values\attrs.xml
[2011-08-04 21:50:06 - Android Framework Parser] Searchable declare-styleable SearchableActionKey not found in file C:\Android\android-sdk\platforms\android-10\data\res\values\attrs.xml
[2011-08-04 21:50:06 - Android Framework Parser] AppWidget declare-styleable AppWidgetProviderInfo not found in file C:\Android\android-sdk\platforms\android-10\data\res\values\attrs.xml
[2011-08-04 21:50:06] Warning, ADT/SDK Mismatch! The following elements are declared by ADT but not by the SDK: manifest
```

I checked the directory and found `attrs.xml` is missing. I retargeted the project to other Android version, say 3.0, the issue disappeared, since there is `attrs.xml` in its corresponding directory.

Why is this? How can I fix it?

Comment: Have you checked to make sure you aren't using any elements introduced in 3.0 in your new project?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe just had to clean your project and rebuild

Comment: But I really didn't see the attrs.xml file in the directory. Can anybody check his 2.3.3 SDK installation?

Answer (score 0):

This error will occur when installation fails sometimes.

You are missing C:\Android\android-sdk\platforms\android-10\data\res\values\attrs.xml file .

This means in your android root directory under your data\res\values\attrs.xml file .

This file is missing. So you have to reinstall specific version or change your android version .

Answer (score 0):

for example :it says

> "MenuItem not found in file
>   D:\Android\sdk\platforms\android-14\data\res\values\attrs.xml"
>
> "MenuItem not found in file"

File is in directory but "MenuItem" isnt in it.